# Tomcat Docker Image on EC2 instance: Public IP returns 404

Tags: docker, tomcat, amazon-ec2

I installed Tomcat Docker Image on Amazon EC2 Linux virtual machine by executing the following commands in the terminal:

```
docker pull tomcat 

docker run --name tomcat-server -p 8080:8080 tomcat:latest
```

When I try to access tomcat instance by EC2 public IP:

```
http://35.171.195.176:8080/
```

The following response is returned:

```
HTTP Status 404 - Not Found
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the followiing article:
https://www.topzenith.com/2020/07/http-status-404-not-found-docker-tomcat-image.html

> Based on the docker community request, webapps folder has been moved
> to the webapps.dist folder, which means webapps folder is empty and
> there are no files to serve on the browser. That is why 404 was
> returned.

To re-enable the webapps, you need to copy the files from webapps.dist to webapps. Here are the steps to run:

```
docker pull tomcat:latest
 
docker run -d --name mytomcat -p 8080:8080 tomcat:latest
 
docker exec -it mytomcat /bin/bash
 
cd webapps.dist/
 
cp -R * ../webapps
 
exit
```